# how to join two table and display the result in ascending or descending order of sum

Tags: php, mysql

I having great difficulty to join two table and get the result like following way .

```
table 1
id  |company_name   | fee

1   |company2       |1000
2   |company1       |2000
3   |company1       |4000
4   |company3       |3000


table 2

company_name    | product

company1        |A
company1        |B
company3        |c
company2        |D
```

And expected result should be like this..

```
company_name   | product | fee

company1       |A        |6000
company1       |B        |6000
company3       |C        |3000
company2       |D        |2000
```

Is that possible?.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: No it's not possible. I think so. There is no unique value.

Answer (score 2):

**select t1.company_name,t2.product,sum(fee) as fee from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.company_name=t2.company_name group by t1.company_name,t2.product order by sum(fee) asc**

I have not tested it, but it should be something around these lines. The key here is to use "sum" in combination with a group by clause of both name and product.

Comment: I can confirm that it works... (actually tested it) :)

Comment: One thing... add a `AS fee` for the `SUM()`

Comment: @Alexander thanks for the solution , i added 'order by sum(fee) asc' to get final answer

Comment: Glad that it worked. I have added your comment. Accept the answer if you think it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

use following sql

```
    SELECT T1.company_name,T2.product ,sum(T1.fee) as fee from TABLE1 
    T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON 
T1.company_name=T2.company_name GROUP BY T2.compnat_name,T2.product
```

Comment: please check this and let me know

Comment: Sorry but why are you reposting the same solution I have already posted ? Dont you check what the other people are answering?

Comment: @Alexander Sorry i'm not riposting your answer. you have submit your answer while i'm typing it i noticed it only after i submit. if you want i can remove my one

Comment: Yeah no worries, i did not check the timestamp of you answer. Its very close to mine. I can see we have been writing in parallel.